# Jquery call a function from external file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a script

```
   <script src="/_layouts/SP.js" type="text/ecmascript"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">

     function ViewItem()
    {
this function calls sucess function or failure function }

function success() {

 }

  function failed(sender, args) {
 }
   </script>
```

This script has to call sp.js which i refered in html page.
I need to write this script in seperate file and call this function viewitem from my html page

Comment: And what's your problem/question? I recommend to remove the `type` attributes.

Comment: You don't have to use TYPE there, and why are you using type as ecmascript?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the comment and ecmascript is for getting list from sharepoint and this viewitem() function need to access that SP.js file. Now i need to place this script in seperate .js file and call that viewitem function

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use TYPE there, and why are you using type as ecmascript?

Good programming practice is that you use the filename in lowercases, I am not sure if that is the issue (that your file is sp.js and you are calling SP.js) but sometimes it is on linux machines

Comment: Thanks for the answer it is SP.js which is sharepoint file which i have no control of

Comment: Wait, do you mean you want to create a new JS file with the script above and call that JS in your HTML?

Comment: Yes and call it in html file

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: What you need to do is put the script
`<script type="text/javascript">

     function ViewItem()
    {
this function calls sucess function or failure function }

function success() {

 }

  function failed(sender, args) {
 }
   </script>`
in a seperate file let's say "myscript.js"

Then on your HTML page call both script files like this:
<script src="sp.js"></script>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>